# JSP display dynamic data from tables in certain format

Tags: java, jsp

I have 5 tables from which I have to get data and display this data in a html table.

Problem I have is to create dynamic table in front-end (JSP) in certain format.  Table headers are part of this tables data.

For ex:  If I get the following data from database tables:

```
        ROW1:  thead1, rowhead1 , data11, data12, data13, data14        
        ROW2:  thead2, rowhead2 , data21, data22, data23, data24        
        ROW3:  thead3, rowhead3 , data31, data32, data33, data34        
        ROW4:  thead4, rowhead4 , data41, data42, data43, data44
```

How can I represent this data in html table as following?

```
             thead1      thead2     thead3      thead4
 rowhead1    data1       data2      data3       data14
 rowhead2    data21      data22     data23      data24
 rowhead3    data31      data32     data33      data34
 rowhead4    data41      data42     data43      data44
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to read our [ask] page to help you formulate a great question.  You are much more likely to get a good answer from the community if you put some effort into your question.

Comment: Your data is 'stored' in a RecordSet, Map, List? Can you show us where you're stuck at? Plus, are you on jstl/el or bare java code in JSP? If you  provide a sketch of code it could be useful to help...

Comment: My data is set in List<ModelClass>.  ModelClass contains all the data.  I am stuck at formatting the table.  How to represent the data from ModelClass as <thead> and <rowhead>.  I am using JSP/JSTL